# Monte Carlo Method crash?

Tags: montecarlo

I have a big problem trying to implement Monte Carlo Method to this function:

```
D=log(T)
```

Where `T` is a measured time, so `T>0`, and, obviously, it has a normal distribution.

I have 10 measured values of `T` in the experiment, so I calculate:

```
m_T (mean of T)  = 3.0 seconds
s_T (standard deviation of T)= 1.5 seconds
```

And, with this parameters I simulate `T` and, then, D:

```
T = Normal(m_T, s_T)
D=log(Normal(m_T, s_T)
```

But in `D` the program returns an error. When I depurate I find that the error is because Normal `(m_T, s_T)` have some NEGATIVE values, so log(NEGATIVE) crash!

I’m blocked, I don’t know how to continue… any suggestion?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the normal distribution always yields a finite probability for negative values. Then what you have measured (time) has not *strictly* a normal distribution.

A [truncated normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) assigns a probability of 0 to every value that do not fall in a certain bound, but by ignoring values below 0 your will modify the mean and variance of the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments:

1. `obviously, it has a normal distribution.` This isn't obvious in the slightest. What might be better would be to use a [Log Normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution). I strongly suspect that a truncated normal isn't what you are after. Using your parameters, we get the figure are the end. Notice that it has a rather high probability at `x=0`.
2. Instead, you want to use Log-Normal, exponential, or some other more suitable distribution. You can match the [moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Location_and_scale) from the true distribution to your observed values or use their maximum likelihood estimators.

[image]

Comment: You an Javier are right, thank you very much! Now I doubt between truncated normal or lognormal. I think that truncated normal makes more sense, because 'time' is normal but its domain is t>=0 (i.e. normal-truncated) but it never behave in the exponential way.